# A file added to Azure App Service is not served

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I need to add a file apple-app-site-association without extension to my Azure App Service.

It is not a web application I created myself, rather, it was generated for me by Azure Communication Service. I followed this manual to build it: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/tutorials/virtual-visits.

The file should be in the .well-known folder in the root directory. I added the file using Azure CLI (or I can add it using Kudu). I can see that the file is there:

[image]

But when I try to access the file in a browser using url, I get an error:

> 404  The page you are trying to reach is unavailable. The page may
> have been removed, deleted or the URL incorrectly entered.

The same happens if I place the file right in the root folder:

[image]

As I did not create the website myself, I cannot configure the file in web.config or something like that. Is there anything that can be done to let the file be served?

**ADDED:**

Here is my web.config file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:
     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    
    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true">
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled
      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->

    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>

    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />
    </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Here is what I see in the log:

```
2023-04-20T21:45:27  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service. The default timeout is 2 hours. Change the timeout with the App Setting SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT (in seconds).
2023-04-20 21:44:40 LATICRETE-VIDEO-CALLS-DEV GET /.well-known/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json X-ARR-LOG-ID=aaaca29b-0a3b-4e88-ba66-a17742bf5fd3 443 - 64.224.255.94 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/94.0.4606.81+Safari/537.36 - https://laticrete-video-calls-dev.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/apple-app-site-association laticrete-video-calls-dev.azurewebsites.net 404 0 0 1582 1497 15
2023-04-20 21:44:44 LATICRETE-VIDEO-CALLS-DEV GET /.well-known/apple-app-site-association X-ARR-LOG-ID=952ecc36-022f-4f9f-bccd-19b85cd6f2f0 443 - 64.224.255.94 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/94.0.4606.81+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=922866e38fa5d4c487637e0a828c7b118f8c296b457d01e9dd13a2fdcdce47d9;+ARRAffinitySameSite=922866e38fa5d4c487637e0a828c7b118f8c296b457d01e9dd13a2fdcdce47d9 - laticrete-video-calls-dev.azurewebsites.net 404 0 0 1582 1739 171
2023-04-20 21:44:44 LATICRETE-VIDEO-CALLS-DEV GET /.well-known/IframeError.css X-ARR-LOG-ID=185ff08a-b8f8-48aa-a0c9-642d52f63476 443 - 64.224.255.94 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/94.0.4606.81+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=922866e38fa5d4c487637e0a828c7b118f8c296b457d01e9dd13a2fdcdce47d9;+ARRAffinitySameSite=922866e38fa5d4c487637e0a828c7b118f8c296b457d01e9dd13a2fdcdce47d9 https://laticrete-video-calls-dev.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/apple-app-site-association laticrete-video-calls-dev.azurewebsites.net 404 0 0 1582 1647 0
2023-04-20 21:44:44 LATICRETE-VIDEO-CALLS-DEV GET /.well-known/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json X-ARR-LOG-ID=3360d0a1-0615-43b8-b645-a0598e3d0b07 443 - 64.224.255.94 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/94.0.4606.81+Safari/537.36 - https://laticrete-video-calls-dev.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/apple-app-site-association laticrete-video-calls-dev.azurewebsites.net 404 0 0 1582 1497 15
2023-04-20 21:45:19 LATICRETE-VIDEO-CALLS-DEV GET /.well-known/apple-app-site-association X-ARR-LOG-ID=8ec44351-8109-4c19-a578-28c95dac6dad 443 - 64.224.255.94 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/94.0.4606.81+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=922866e38fa5d4c487637e0a828c7b118f8c296b457d01e9dd13a2fdcdce47d9;+ARRAffinitySameSite=922866e38fa5d4c487637e0a828c7b118f8c296b457d01e9dd13a2fdcdce47d9 - laticrete-video-calls-dev.azurewebsites.net 404 0 0 1582 1739 11
2023-04-20 21:45:19 LATICRETE-VIDEO-CALLS-DEV GET /.well-known/IframeError.css X-ARR-LOG-ID=9203a058-8841-42cc-a1e3-9fdac11a8d14 443 - 64.224.255.94 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/94.0.4606.81+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=922866e38fa5d4c487637e0a828c7b118f8c296b457d01e9dd13a2fdcdce47d9;+ARRAffinitySameSite=922866e38fa5d4c487637e0a828c7b118f8c296b457d01e9dd13a2fdcdce47d9 https://laticrete-video-calls-dev.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/apple-app-site-association laticrete-video-calls-dev.azurewebsites.net 404 0 0 1582 1647 11
2023-04-20 21:45:19 LATICRETE-VIDEO-CALLS-DEV GET /.well-known/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json X-ARR-LOG-ID=5c9a0ccb-73f6-4ff7-8c57-439a5c35dbcd 443 - 64.224.255.94 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/94.0.4606.81+Safari/537.36 - https://laticrete-video-calls-dev.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/apple-app-site-association laticrete-video-calls-dev.azurewebsites.net 404 0 0 1582 1497 0
```

Comment: What do you see in your webserver logfiles? Are you using Windows or Linux-based Azure App Service? What's in your `web.config` file?

Comment: @Dai It is Windows. I added my web.config contents and log info to my question.

Comment: I think your URL Rewrite rule `<rule name="DynamicContent">` is capturing all requests for basically _everything_ - what happens if you temporarily disable all `<rewrite>` rules?

Comment: Also enable Failed Request Tracing (in Azure Portal) and look at the tracelogs for those requests.

Comment: @Dai Sorry, I am not good at this. How should I disable the rules? Just comment the lines out? Also, I enabled Failed Request Tracing. How can I see the tracelogs?

Comment: Just XML comment-out `<!-- -->` the `<rewrite>` element - and Failed Request Tracing logs are under `D:\home\LogFiles\W3SVCxxxxx\fr00xxxx.xml`. Download the entire directory (so all the `fr000xxxx.xml` files _and_ the `freb.xsl` file) then open them in Internet Explorer 11 on your desktop (yes, seriously).

Comment: @Dai I commented out what you said, and got "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.." Should I get the log with this change, or I can restore the web.config?

Comment: It sounds like you made a mistake when editing your `web.config` file

Comment: @Dai Were you talking about everything within <rewrite></rewrite>?

Comment: @Dai Also, could you please tell where is that D:\home? Is the LogFiles folder the same I see at the same place where the "site" folder is? If so, it is empty after I restored the web.config and used the url again. Or maybe the logs need more time to show up?

Comment: I think you should contact Azure Support for assistance - I can't really help you using only SO comment replies...